# Dart 2.17 has warning when using code snipplet

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just update dart sdk to 2.17 and when I use snipplet (in VScode) to auto generate code for  Stateless/Stateful it auto import these two package.

But it tell me warning `Don't import implementation files from another package`. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are missing that these are built-in snippets by the official Dart extension for VSCode. Of course we can manually `import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';` but the issue is that it seems to be a bug by the Dart extension itself.

It is currently being tracked here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/49081. There is no fix yet it seems but you can create your own snippets in VSCode and use those.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you importing implementation files from Flutter? If you have Flutter setup right you do not need to import anything like this.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear, I'm not that good at english. I mean vscode **auto** import it when I use auto complete (code snipplet)

Comment: I just curious why it auto, but have warnings

Answer (score -1):

You're importing files from a package's `src` directory.  That is not normal.  You're directly importing a package's internal, private files.

The analysis warning tells you the name of the warning (`implementation_imports`), and your IDE should allow you to click on it to get more details:

https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#implementation_imports

Instead use:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
```